# Catch cast exception in @PathVariable when type is Long and Client sent String(not number)

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot controller with param `@PathVariable long stopPointId`, when user will be send request like "url/StopPoints/1" everything work perfect, but when request will be look like "url/StopPoints/StopPointNumber" nothing will be happening. I want to catch this situation and throw my custom error because user need to know, that param only take long value. For instance: You are not able to pass String as parameter. You should use number value e.g 123."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to handle the `NumberFormatException` that would be thrown by Spring Boot while trying to typecast a String into a Long.

This is my custom HTTP-Response class, but I trust you have your own...

```
package com.stackoverflow.rav.StackOverflowExamples.api;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

import java.util.Date;

public class HttpResponse {

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss", timezone = "UTC")
    private Date timeStampUTC;
    private int httpStatusCode;
    private HttpStatus httpStatus;
    private String reason;
    private String message;
    
    /* Include setters, getters, constructors, or use Lombok */

}
```

Then the exception handler... (exception message should be generic in order to increase reusability)

```
package com.stackoverflow.rav.StackOverflowExamples.api;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestControllerAdvice;

@RestControllerAdvice
public class ExampleExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(NumberFormatException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<HttpResponse> accountDisabledException() {
        return createHttpResponse(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Should pass long not string!");
    }

    private ResponseEntity<HttpResponse> createHttpResponse(HttpStatus httpStatus, String message) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new HttpResponse(
                httpStatus.value(),
                httpStatus,
                httpStatus.getReasonPhrase().toUpperCase(),
                message.toUpperCase()),
                httpStatus);
    }
}
```

Finally the controller...

```
package com.stackoverflow.rav.StackOverflowExamples.api;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ExampleController extends ExampleExceptionHandler {

    @GetMapping("/url/{someValue}")
    public String hello(@PathVariable("someValue") long someValue) {

        return "You entered: " +someValue;
    }
}
```

If all goes well you should get a response like the screen-snippet below when doing `http://localhost:8080/url/abcd`
[image]

This answer might look lengthy, but we are Java developers :D